# Raster extraction returns NA's only

Tags: r, extract, r-raster

I am trying to create a rasterstack of 7 rasters named `stack`.
this seems to work well, as when I use `freq(stack)` it returns frequencies for the rasters that are part of it, for example for one of the rasters:

```
$Slope_Final
     value  count
[1,]     0 414933
[2,]     1  94763
[3,]     2   6622
[4,]     3    917
[5,]     4    195
[6,]     5     22
[7,]    NA 487146
```

Yet when trying `summary(stack)` it returns

```
Error in .local(object, ...) : no cell values associated with this RasterBrick
```

This seems to contradict each other? Strangely enough,  `print(stack)`  does work.
As I continue, and use the `raster::extract` function,

```
extraction <- extract(stack,points)
```

where points is a spatialpoints dataframe with a few columns like date and time, the returned matrix is 3145 rows of NA only;

```
> summary(extraction)
 Elevation_Final Landcover_Final Primroad_Final Secroad_Final  GPW_Final      Slope_Final    Water_Final   
 Mode:logical    Mode:logical    Mode:logical   Mode:logical   Mode:logical   Mode:logical   Mode:logical  
 NA's:3145       NA's:3145       NA's:3145      NA's:3145      NA's:3145      NA's:3145      NA's:3145
```

```
points$Lat
```

and

```
 points$Lon
```

do return coordinates! They are of class integer.
In case it is relevant; the extens of  `stack`  and  `points`

```
 extent(stack)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -265959.9 
xmax       : 873040.1 
ymin       : 4619541 
ymax       : 5501541 

extent(points)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -97.1336 
xmax       : -83.54935 
ymin       : 43.6795 
ymax       : 49.0001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you showed more code, including all the messages you get. For example, you say you have a RasterStack, but the error message says you have a RasterBrick. Now that should not matter too much in most cases, but, who knows, it does matter here. `summary` takes a sample if the files are very large, and since you have many NA's perhaps it was an unlucky sample (seems unlikely) --- there would be a message in that case.

Ideally, you would recreate the problem by creating some similar data with code. That may be difficult here, but you could still show the workflow and `show(stack)` and `show(points)`.

From the extents, one can assume that `points` has a longitude/latitude coordinate reference system, but `stack` clearly does not have that. The also do not overlap and hence you get all `NAs` . That is a good thing here, if they had, by coincidence, overlapped you might have gotten values, but the wrong values.

Comment: Hello Robert,

It became clear that I made a mistake when I simply assumed that 

`coordinates(wolves) <- c("Lon","Lat")`
  +  
`projection(wolves) <- crs(waterdist)`

would reproject my spatialpointsdataframe to the crs of all the rasters that are part of the stack, this is why the result from extracting was empty!

Still, the `summary()` function did not work on the stack for some reason, while `show()`, `print()`, ... did. I'm not sure why this would be the case, or why it would call it a RasterBrick when the env calls it a RasterStack.

Thanks once again for your help!!